# Performing logistic regression analysis in python using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression analysis but I don't know which part am i mistaken in my code. It gives error on the line `logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)`. But it seems okay as i checked from different sources. Can anybody help?
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/utkusenel/Documents/Data Analyzing/data.csv", header=0, sep=";")
data = pd.DataFrame(df)

x = data.drop(columns=["churn"])  #features
y = data.churn  # target variable
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of data stored in the DataFrame ?

Comment: state;account_length;area_code;international_plan;voice_mail_plan;number_vmail_messages;total_day_minutes;total_day_calls;total_day_charge;total_eve_minutes;total_eve_calls;total_eve_charge;total_night_minutes;total_night_calls;total_night_charge;total_intl_minutes;total_intl_calls;total_intl_charge;number_customer_service_calls;churn;
1;KS;128;area_code_415;no;yes;25;265.1;110;45.07;197.4;99;16.78;244.7;91;11.01;10;3;2.7;1;no
2;OH;107;area_code_415;no;yes;26;161.6;123;27.47;195.5;103;16.62;254.4;103;11.45;13.7;3;3.7;1;no @dm2

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data. See how it's done here https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898

Comment: what is the exception being raised? Can you include that too?

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed) and should not be included here (it just creates unnecessary clutter). Same holds for irrelevant imports (edited out - look how much cleaner your code looks now).

Comment: Sorry guys for the lack of format knowledge. I am new to this platform. @RichieV

Comment: @UtkuŞenel If you think the answer below answers your question, please make sure to mark it answered by clicking on the check mark below upvote and downvote buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

1. Your first row of headers has a `';'` at the end. So it is going to read an extra column. You need to remove that `';'` after `churn`.
2. The training data that you are trying to use here, X_train, is going to have multiple text/categorical columns. You need to convert these into numbers. Check out OneHotEncoder here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html and LabelEncoder here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

After you have converted your text and categorical data to numbers and removed the extra `';'` separator, run your algorithm again.